# Which 3D engine for ruby

Tags: ruby, 3d-engine

i am looking for a 3D engine for developing a ruby game. i found some like G3Druby or ogrerb.

which one is better to use and has better functionality? is there any other engine better than these?

Answer (score 5):

Both seem to be wrappers around G3D and Ogre, so you actually should be comparing if G3D or Ogre are better for your needs. Most of your out-of-ruby accesses through the wrapper will be while setting up your scene so the grunt work (each frame) is still done within the C/C++ libraries and on graphics hardware. So you should be comparing those two libraries instead.

I don't know G3D but it seems to offer offline rendering features that Ogre lacks. Ogre is usually first choice if you need the vast functionality of a professional game render engine and you'll find tons of documentation or forum posts on just about any topic you'll encounter.

So it just depends on what exactly you will be using it for.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Irrlict looks very impressive. It also seems to follow some emerging trends that Ruby 1.9 takes advantage of, which I like to see. Have a look. More impressive rendering and a better following than G3Druby in my opinion.

http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/screenshots-projects.html

Comment: There seem to be some attempts at wrapping Irrlicht for ruby but all seem to be at very early development stages.

Comment: Irrlicht is related to ruby ... how?

Comment: The OP was looking for an API for ruby.