# 3d game engines for Ruby or Python?

Tags: python, ruby, game-engine

Are there any 3d game engines for these ?

Comment: Except for the "or Python", duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314543

Answer (score 8):

Sure, e.g, for Python: [PySoy](http://www.pysoy.org/) and [Python-Ogre](http://www.python-ogre.org/) and [Blender3D](http://www.blender.org/) and [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/) and [Peace Engine](http://www.geocities.com/peacedeveloper/peaceengine/PeaceEngine.htm) and ... how many do you **want** to hear about, again!?-)

Answer (score 3):

I have worked a little bit with Panda3D, and it is a competent professional 3D engine. I haven't really worked with any of the other engines, though. If you are trying to start out with some 3D programming, I would recommend Blender3D because it is coupled with free 3D modeling software, which makes it easier to get models into your code. With Panda3D you will need to download and install an extension to allow you to export 3D models from software into a format the engine can recognize.

I have only used Panda3D, so I cannot compare the merits of the engines. From my basic knowledge (very basic), I would say that Blender3D is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i like to use pygame. Its easy, free and fast.